how do I configure composer in my running php & nginx container in Docker?
I've been working with Docker for about a few days and I confused with installing & running different extensions in Docker with composer.The main issue is that I can't properly install compoer inside  my php dockerfile & docker-compose.My goal is to install the composer itself and guzzle library for my running php & nginx docker container.
php dockerfile:
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY ./src/composer.* ./
RUN composer install
COPY ./src .

docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx/
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/php.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log
      - ./vendor/:/var/www/html/
      - ./composer.json/:/var/www/html/
      - ./composer.lock/:/var/www/html/
networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge


The volumes: in your Compose file have composer.json and composer.lock in the base directory, but the Dockerfile COPY statement comes from a src subdirectory.  Is this mismatch causing a problem?  (I might delete the Compose volumes: block, since it hides most of what's in your image and it means the container isn't runnable without having a copy of the code on the host system.)

I've deleted this volume, thanks.
The problem is that I've run composer init, added guzzle as for the main package and autoloader, but now I need to configure both dockerfile PHP and docker-compose.
I've tried different tutorials but still having issues while I run the container.

You shouldn't need to change anything in docker-compose.yml.  It will run the image as it's build in the Dockerfile; it's not really aware of what tools might be installed there.

Oh, thanks so much.
Anyway, could you help me to write the right instructions in order to run composer inside my docker container?I'm stucked at the moment.

"different extensions in Docker with composer" - what does that mean? Composer can not install any extension.  "I can't properly install compoer inside my php dockerfile & docker-compose" - why not? What exactly is not working with the given configuration?

require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. What happened when you ran composer install?

You are running composer install inside the container and then mount the volume of src on top of the created /var/www/html/ directory basically hiding all the changes made when you build the container. You should either not mount the volume or run composer install outside of the container.
