Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2
I'm just exploring Docker and containerization for a little bit and I've stacked with the problem in the title:
Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 2

Here is my Dockerfile PHP:
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
COPY src/composer.json /var/www/html/
RUN composer install --no-dev -d /var/www/html/
COPY src/ /var/www/html/

docker-compose.yaml:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - internal
    volumes:
      - ./src/:/var/www/html/
      - ./logs/php.log:/var/log/fpm-php.www.log`

My project also includes this image file.
I've tried to change both PHP dockerfile and docker-compose but it doesn't work.
Thank you in advance for your help guys.

Are you getting that error from the image build stage or when you're running the built image?  (The volumes: in the Compose file will hide everything in the image's /var/www/html directory, it looks like including the results of composer install.)

I'm getting this error when I type docker compose up -d when I go to my localhost.

You probably don't want the composer.json in the html subdir, but in the project base, which is (presumably?) one dir above that. What does your project's directory layout look like?

How is this problem different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78617967/how-do-i-configure-composer-in-my-running-php-nginx-container-in-docker?

How about this failure to open vendor/autoload.php?
